# How to create two JOIN-tables so that I can compare attributes within?

Tags: sql

I take a Database course in which we have listings of AirBnBs and need to be able to do some SQL queries in the Relationship-Model we made from the data, but I struggle with one in particular :

I have two tables that we are interested in, `Billing` and `Amenities`. The first one have the `id` and `price` of listings, the second have `id` and `wifi` (let's say, to simplify, that it equals 1 if there is Wifi, 0 otherwise). Both have other attributes that we don't really care about here.

So the query is, "What is the difference in the average price of listings with and without Wifi ?"

My idea was to build to JOIN-tables, one with listings that have wifi, the other without, and compare them easily :

```
SELECT avg(B.price - A.price) as averagePrice
FROM (
    SELECT Billing.price, Billing.id
    FROM Billing
    INNER JOIN Amenities
    ON Billing.id = Amenities.id
    WHERE Amenities.wifi = 0
) A, ( 
    SELECT Billing.price, Billing.id
    FROM Billing
    INNER JOIN Amenities
    ON Billing.id = Amenities.id
    WHERE Amenities.wifi = 1) B
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

Obviously this doesn't work... I am pretty sure that there is a far easier solution to it tho, what do I miss ?

(And by the way, is there a way to compute the absolute between the difference of price ?)

I hope that I was clear enough, thank you for your time !

Edit : As mentionned in the comments, forgot to say that, but both tables have `id`as their primary key, so that there is one row per listing.

Comment: Do both the `Billing` and `Amenities` table have a single row for each listing?

Comment: Yes ! Sorry I forgot to put that, but both tables have `id` as primary keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we're working with data like the following (problems with your data model are noted below):

```
Billing
+------------+---------+
| listing_id |  price  |
+------------+---------+
|          1 | 1500.00 |
|          2 | 1700.00 |
|          3 | 1800.00 |
|          4 | 1900.00 |
+------------+---------+

Amenities
+------------+------+
| listing_id | wifi |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    1 |
|          2 |    1 |
|          3 |    0 |
+------------+------+
```

Notice that I changed "id" to "listing_id" to make it clear what it was (using "id" as an attribute name is problematic anyways). Also, note that one listing doesn't have an entry in the Amenities table. Depending on your data, that may or may not be a concern (again, refer to the bottom for a discussion of your data model).

Based on this data, your averages should be as follows:

- Listings with wifi average $1600 (Listings 1 and 2)
- Listings without wifi (just 3) average 1800).

So the difference would be $200.

To achieve this result in SQL, it may be helpful to first get the average cost per amenity (whether wifi is offered). This would be obtained with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Amenities.wifi AS has_wifi, 
    AVG(Billing.price) AS avg_cost
FROM Billing
    INNER JOIN Amenities ON
        Amenities.listing_id = Billing.listing_id
GROUP BY Amenities.wifi
```

which gives you the following results:

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| has_wifi |       avg_cost        |
+----------+-----------------------+
|        0 | 1800.0000000000000000 |
|        1 | 1600.0000000000000000 |
+----------+-----------------------+
```

So far so good. So now we need to calculate the difference between these 2 rows. There are a number of different ways to do this, but one is to use a `CASE` expression to make one of the values negative, and then simply take the `SUM` of the result (note that I'm using a CTE, but you can also use a sub-query):

```
WITH 
    avg_by_wifi(has_wifi, avg_cost) AS
    (
        SELECT Amenities.wifi, AVG(Billing.price)
        FROM Billing
        INNER JOIN Amenities ON
            Amenities.listing_id = Billing.listing_id
        GROUP BY Amenities.wifi 
    )
SELECT 
    ABS(SUM
    (
        CASE
            WHEN has_wifi = 1 THEN avg_cost 
            ELSE -1 * avg_cost
        END
    ))
FROM avg_by_wifi
```

which gives us the expected value of `200`.

---

Now regarding your data model:

- If both your `Billing` and `Amenities` table only have 1 row for each listing, it makes sense to combine them into 1 table. For example: `Listings(listing_id, price, wifi)`
- However, this is still problematic, because you probably have a bunch of other amenities you want to model (pool, sauna, etc.) So you might want to model a many-to-many relationship between listings and amenities using an intermediate table:

```
Listings(listing_id, price)
Amenities(amenity_id, amenity_name)
ListingsAmenities(listing_id, amenity_id)
```

This way, you could list multiple amenities for a given listing without having to add additional columns. It also becomes easy to store additional information about an amenity: What's the wifi password? How deep is the pool? etc.

Of course, using this model makes your original query (difference in average cost of listings by wifi) a bit tricker, but definitely still doable.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Not sure that I truly understood your second part, but I am digging into it !

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN a.wifi = 0 THEN b.price END) as avg_no_wifi,
       AVG(CASE WHEN a.wifi = 1 THEN b.price END) as avg_wifi           
 FROM Billing b JOIN
     Amenities a
     ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.wifi IN (0, 1);
```

You can use a `-` if you want the difference instead of the specific values.